# Evaluating $\int _{-100}^{100}\lfloor {x^3}\rfloor \,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Is there an alternative better solution?

$I=\displaystyle\int_{-100}^{100}\lfloor x^3\rfloor\,dx$
$=\displaystyle\int_{-100}^{100}\lfloor(100-100-x)^3\rfloor\,dx$  $\quad$ [$\because\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx=\int_{a}^{b}f(a+b-x)\,dx$]

$=\displaystyle\int_{-100}^{100}\lfloor-x^3\rfloor\,dx$

$=\displaystyle\int_{-100}^{100}(-\lfloor x^3\rfloor-1)\,dx$  $\quad$ [$\because \lfloor x\rfloor+\lfloor-x\rfloor=-1$ when $x\notin \mathbb{Z}$]

$\Rightarrow I=-I-200$ $\quad$ $\Rightarrow I=-100$

**EDIT.** Is there any area interpretation of the integral?

Comment: No, but it's a good approach.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that but I posted an A that's a little bit different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For $0>x\not \in \Bbb Z$ we have $[-x]=-[x]-1.$  $$\text {So }\quad \int_{-100}^0[y^3]\;dy = \int_0^{100}(-[x^3]-1)\;dx$$ is obtained by letting $y=-x.$ $$\text { Therefore } \quad \int_{-100}^{100}[x^3]\;dx=\int_{-100}^0 [y^3]\;dy+\int_0^{100}[x^3]\;dx=$$ $$=\int_0^{100}(-[x^3]-1)\;dx+\int_0^{100} [x^3]\;dx=$$ $$=\int_0^{100} (-1-[x^3]+[x^3])\;dx=\int_0^{100}(-1)\;dx=-100.$$

Remark: (Added July 2019). We have $[-x] \ne -[x]-1$  if $0\ge x\in \Bbb Z.$  But the integrals in the 1st displayed line are still equal because $\{y\in [-100,0]: [y^3]\ne -[y^3]-1\}$ is finite.

Comment: Do you mean to say that x€Z, constitute only isolated points on the graph and hence doesn't affect the integration?

Comment: @thewitness .Exactly.... I received an upvote yesterday so I looked at this and was surprised to see that after 3 years and 8 upvotes and an Acceptance, my 1st sentence, which  said "For $0>x...$", not "For  $0>x\not \in \Bbb Z$..." was false, but nobody else noticed.